Colophon - beginning or end? What's your opinion?
Most people here would know that "properly," a Colophon is a decoration at the end of a work. However, there are very many words that are widely used completely incorrectly (and often oppositely) to the earlier "correct" meaning. (Aside - my random favorite example, apocryphal.) I feel that today colophon is often used for a decoration at the start of a work. (That is to say, in a "dedication -like" position; but a colophon is completely different in tone and function to a dedication.) And that it is, let's say, normal, and unremarkable to do so; a colophon can now be at the start, or the end; that's the new norm. Of course, I could be totally wrong.
What is the opinion of those gathered here?
Eg, a decoration on the frontispiece of a script, labelled colophon


Did you mean Roman Holiday with Audrey Hepburn and Gregory Peck?

(Yosef - yes, maybe there's a typo or?)  Then it's the naatural morphing of natural language  Quite right, that's what I'm asking: it seems to me that colophon is now often (more?) used as a label on a frontspiece, rather than an endpiece.  Hence, as asked, I'm seeking views on whether others think that ..

Graphic design SE suggests ornaments or flourishes. It would be good if you could include an actual example (preferably an image).

@StuartF ? Thanks .. there's an example (image) right in the question my man!  :) There was a screenplay laying on my desk with a colophon (front page, not back!) so I took a photoi and it's there in the question. A colophon is originally written, ie, just like say a dedication or afterward.  but yes it could be a drawing, etc.  That really doesn't change the question, I guess ...

@StuartF a good example is you know that famous series of programming / sysadmin books, they have an animal drawing, and there's sometimes a colophon explaining the drawing (however, i don't recall if the colophon is at the start or end of the book, or varies (I think like on the cover sometimes) {just to be obtuse I never found that to be a good example of a colophon, coilophons should be "about the work" rather than "entertaining ancillary info", but that's way off topic anyways)

OED: Colophon

1.† ‘Finishing stroke’, ‘crowning touch’. Obsolete.
His Colophon is how to resist and represse Atheisme. R. Burton,
Anatomy of Melancholy (ed. 3) iii.iv.ii. i. 621

This gives a clue as the where a colophon could, originally, be found in a book.

2.a. The inscription or device, sometimes pictorial or emblematic, formerly placed at the end of a book or manuscript, and containing the
title, the scribe's or printer's name, date and place of printing,
etc. Hence, "from title page to colophon."
In early times the colophon gave the information now given on the title page.

Times change; words change, the position of a colophon changes: "O tempera, o mores!"

Awesome.  Fortuna est que fit cum preparation in occasion incidit


Colophon
A colophon, whose name is from a Greek word meaning "summit" or
"finishing touch," is traditionally an inscription placed at the end
of a book or manuscript, usually with facts that relate to its
production. These details might include the name of the printer and
the date and place of printing. Colophons are found in some
manuscripts and books made as long ago as the 6th century AD. In
Medieval and Renaissance manuscripts, a colophon was often added to
provide facts such as the author's name and the date and place of the
completion of the work, as well as an expression of thanks to those
who assisted in its production.
Eventually, the colophon was included on the blank page opposite the
title page where it consists of usually a one-sentence statement as to
where the book was printed and by whom. It also can be a simple
identifying mark, emblem, or device that is used by a printer or a
publisher on the title page, cover, spine, or jacket. Whatever the
case, they remain a neat feature to discover when perusing books in a
used book store.

[Merriam-Webster]
So 'used incorrectly' is unsound in the light of an accredited dictionary's endorsement. The etymological fallacy.
And note that a colophon may alternatively be an inscription (rather than an ornament), and this seems to be the original usage.

Edwin - how many times can it be said, You Rock
